Seeking AI Tool or Model for Realistic Car Background Replacement
I’m currently working on a project where I need to replace the background of car photos in a highly realistic manner. The goal is to take a car photo, automatically cut out the car, and place it into a new background like a showroom or a garage. I’m particularly interested in ensuring that the car is well-positioned in the new environment with natural-looking shadows.
Does anyone know of any free AI tools or open-source AI models that can handle this task effectively? Ideally, I’m looking for something that can automate the entire process or at least assist in achieving realitics results.
This is the result i want to have:


Asking for tools here is off-topic, but you can ask for models or papers that describe approaches to do that. So, I'd recommend that you edit this post to make it more on-topic.
